# Brownie INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)

Tags: python, brownie, framework

I installed Brownie succefully, and also am able to make a init project from it. But every time I run brownie I get

> **INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)**

I've installed ganache-cli, solidity, and other few dependencies, but yet don't know why is it coming up:

```
> brownie
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.15.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum
```

Comment: were you able to solve it ?